# Keyboard stops for a few seconds then catches up

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I built a new computer and installed Ubuntu, and when I added my wireless keyboard it works, but it cannot keep up (the keyboard worked on my old Ubuntu computer). When I type there is a huge delay between me pressing a key and it actually showing up on screen. This is happening in many apps (terminal included) and games. It is also sometime ignoring key presses as well and adding extra strokes so I get the same key press 2+ times.

The delay can range from a couple seconds to 30 seconds. It is sometimes very responsive as well, and this behaviour keeps coming and going.

I opened the BIOS, and it was even slow there. Could it be because I have them in 3.0 USB slots, and not 2.0 USB slots?

How can I fix this?

#### Edit

After moving them to 2.0 slots... the issue seems to have gone away.... almost instantly... I will keep using them and see if this was the issue.

Comment: Did you move the receiver to a different USB port already and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Consider upgrading the kernel of the OS that you just installed. Perhaps there is a kernel level bug and whatever version of Ubuntu you are running doesn't have the latest kernel version installed and thus the bug you experience with that version of kernel and those other USB ports.